# Case for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 inch tablet

Tags: tablet, case

I have a Galaxy Tab 4, 10.1 inch tablet that is in need of a case.

I am looking for a [case](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA17P26Z0738) that is similar to one I had on my Asus Transformer.

Criteria:

- Hard cover folds over the screen
- Opens in such a way that the cover can be completely behind the tablet, allowing me to hold the device flat or lay it flat on a table but have the screen accessible
- Opens in such a way that it can stand up and the angle can be adjusted for better viewing. The previous one I had allowed 3 viewing angles
- Camera (front and rear), volume controls, SD Card port, headphone port and power button must all be uncovered by the case
- Charging port needs to be accessible without removing the case. I do not need it to be accessible when the case is closed. If I can charge it and leave it laying flat on the bookshelf, that is fine.

Budget for this case is under $50.

Comment: This is a test question to see how the community feels about cases/accessories. This scope being discussed in this [meta post](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/267/57).

Comment: Ah, finally a test question. Looking forward to seeing how this does. Do you prefer bulky/durable or minimal/stylish?

Comment: Minimal. The previous case I had (linked in the post) is thin. It would not protect the case if I dropped it onto a hard surface. I'm much more interested in protecting the screen while the tablet is resting and unused and propping it up. I'm *usually* careful with my toys.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the [ProCase BC72090](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KSU6OSE) or another from that family.