# What tempered glass will cover the Moto X Play fully?

Tags: displays, mobile-phone, touchscreen

I have shopped all over Chennai, India and the most popular online shopping portals in India, but I am not able to find a tempered glass for Moto X Play which covers the complete display.

All the tempered glass products I have looked at only covers a part of the screen. 2-3 cm uncovered areas are left in the left and right sides of the screen. I'm looking for a tempered glass covering for Moto X Play that covers the complete display. Does anyone have a good recommendation?

Comment: This is a request for something that does not fall under the definition of hardware in the stack scope.

Comment: @NZKshatriya I'd say that this is still open to discussion at this point, i.e. protective cases/screen protectors may still fall within our scope. See, e.g. [this meta answer](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/267/203) and [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/633/case-for-a-samsung-galaxy-tab-4-10-1-inch-tablet)

Comment: *rips hair out*  Is there a way to, erm, un-vote?